# Error in using angularjs data in form action link in spring mvc web app project

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I m using angularjs to retrieve my data in my spring web app project. it is able to retrieve and display the data in all places i have passed it using {{ }} but in my form-action link it is not able to read the value passed . what is wrong with the syntax?

```
        <div class="container text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <div ng-repeat="product in Data" >
    <div class=col-lg-5>
    <center>
    <img src="<c:url value='/resource/image/{{product.name}}.jpg'/>" />
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class=col-lg-7>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <td>{{product.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <td>Rs.{{product.price}}</td>
    </tr>
^    
till here it displays the data using angular js
    </table>
    </div> 

 <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="cart" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/addtocart?productId={{product.id}}">
^  
here it doesnt read the data passed using angularjs 


 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Add to Cart" />
 </sec:authorize>
 </form:form>
```

Comment: it looks like you have missing closing `div` tags on your html

Comment: Your <img> tag closing two times..

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to below way,because your `ng-controller` `<div>` tag ended before the form as the angular scope is restricted to that `</div>` tag itself your `{{}}` expression in action is not evaluated.

```
<div class="container text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="product in Data">
        <div class=col-lg-5>
          <center>
            <img src="<c:url value='/resource/image/{{product.name}}.jpg'/>" />
          </center>
        </div>
        <div class=col-lg-7>
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
              <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>Description</th>
              <td>{{product.description}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Category</th>
              <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Price</th>
              <td>Rs.{{product.price}}</td>
            </tr>

          </table>
          <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="cart" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/addtocart?productId={{product.id}}">
            <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Add to Cart" />
            </sec:authorize>
          </form:form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you need 2 more closing `div` tags for `<div ng-repeat="product in Data">` and `<div class="container text-center" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">`

Comment: @PrinceG yes you are correct ! updated my answer ..thank you :)

Comment: yes i know about the last two divs that i need to close at the end. but i had closed  <div class=col-lg-7> before the form and not the ng repeat or the ng-controller

Comment: Invalid HTML tag's start or end results in unexpected behaviour  from Angular as it tries to evaluate the DOM in your case it took your <div class=col-lg-7>  end tag as ng-repeat end tag.

Comment: if i add another tag inside the form tag to display product.id , it displays. so i think angular is passing data there